# loop not writing expected output in the dom 15 times

Tags: javascript, html, loops, for-loop, dom

why do the loop not writing expected output in the dom 15 times

I am trying to create an elemnt div 15 times with another div child

here is the code

```
for(let i=1;i<=15;i++){
    let smalldiv=document.createElement("div").textContent=i;
    let pr =document.createElement("div");
    pr.textContent="product";
};
smalldiv.appendChild(pr);
```

Comment: Put the `appendChild()` call inside the loop. You're only appending the last one.

Comment: You're not setting `smalldiv` to the `div`, you're setting it to `i`.

Comment: This code should get an error on the last line. And you're never appending anything to the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

```
let smalldiv=document.createElement("div").textContent=i;
```

doesn't set `smalldiv` to the DIV. When you write

```
let x = y = z;
```

it's equivalent to

```
y = z;
let x = y;
```

so you're setting `smalldiv` to the `textContent` that you assigned `i` to.

And even if you did set `smalldiv` to the DIV, you never append it to the DOM, so you wouldn't see the results.

Since you're appending `pr` to `smalldiv` after the loop, you're just appending the last `pr`. But that won't work either, because the scope of `pr` is the loop body, so you can't refer to it after the loop is done. You should append it inside the loop.

Don't use a DIV for numbered items, use an ordered list `<ol>`, with `<li>` elements within it.

```js
let ol = document.createElement("ol");
for(let i=1;i<=15;i++){
    let pr =document.createElement("li");
    pr.textContent="product";
    ol.appendChild(pr);
};
document.body.appendChild(ol);
```

Answer (score 0):

First create the div smalldiv, then add the textContent.
Then you need to append the elements to the DOM using an element already in the DOM or append to the document.body.

```js
for(let i=1;i<=15;i++){
    // create the div and assign the variable
    let smalldiv=document.createElement("div");
    // set the textContent once created
    smalldiv.textContent = `${i}. `;
    // create new div 'pr'
    let pr = document.createElement("span");
    // assign its content
    pr.textContent="product";
    // append pr to smalldiv
    smalldiv.append(pr);
    // append smalldiv to the body
    document.body.append(smalldiv);
};
```